# codeigniter loop displays multiple entries

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**As of 7/12/17 3PM I have edited the controller, view and model which fixed the code (no more multiple lines, although there is another error, i have fixed it by removing some codes and calling the id in time_sign table in table_model) Thanks.**

I have this **view file** in my Codeigniter project and I need help on this one.

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
           <tr>
               <td class="hidden"><?=$user->id;?></td>
               <td><?=$user->name;?></td>
               <td><?=$sign->timein;?></td>
               <td><?=$sign->timeout;?></td>
               <td width="100px">
                   <a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/tabledisplay/recTime/".$user->id; ?>">
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="time-in">Sign In</button>
                   </a>
               </td>
               <td width="100px">
                   <a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/tabledisplay/recOut/".$user->id; ?>">
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="time-in">Sign Out</button>
                   </a>
               </td>
           </tr>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
```

and this is my **controller** for displaying that view:

```
function index()
{
    $data = array();
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data['users'] = $this->table_model->display_table();
    $this->load->view('table_view', $data);
}
```

Now what it outputs is that there are three copies of each user in a table.
Say for example:

ID - 1

Name - John

ID - 2

Name - Stacy

In the table:

1 . John . Time In: 08:00 . Time Out: 3:00 . Sign In . Sign Out

1 . John . Time In: 08:00 . Time Out: 3:00 . Sign In . Sign Out

1 . John . Time In: 08:00 . Time Out: 3:00 . Sign In . Sign Out

2 . Stacy . Time In: 08:00 . Time Out: 3:00 . Sign In . Sign Out

2 . Stacy . Time In: 08:00 . Time Out: 3:00 . Sign In . Sign Out

2 . Stacy . Time In: 08:00 . Time Out: 3:00 . Sign In . Sign Out

(That sign in/out is actually the button)
And another point when I click the buttons it updates all of the records when I only want a single user to be able to record time.

**Now the output is:**

**1 . John . Time In: 6:00 . Time Out: 8:00 . Sign In . Sign Out**

**2 . Stacy . Time In: 08:00 . Time Out: 3:00 . Sign In . Sign Out**

and for the **model** in recording the time (button):

```
function recordTime($id)
{

     $this->db->select("time-id, timein, timeout");
     $this->db->set('timein', 'NOW()', FALSE);
     $this->db->update('time_sign');
      $query = $this->db->get('time_sign');
      return $query->result();
}
```

**Also, I didn't include the model for displaying so here it is:**

```
function display_table ()
{
      $this->db->select("time_sign.indexuser, CONCAT(lname, ', ', fname, ' ', mname) AS name, users.position, time_sign.timein, time_sign.timeout");
      $this->db->from('users');
      $this->db->join('time_sign', 'time_sign.indexuser = users.id', 'LEFT');
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Is there any mapping between this two tables.?

Answer (score 1):

An Initial Look at this... Your model is a little mixed up and you are not using $id.

First thing, you pass in $id but don't use it.
Secondly, you are mixing up your intentions regarding the db calls performing an update and select...

I think what you are trying to do is this...

```
function recordTime($id)
{
    // Perform the Update
    $this->db->set('timein', 'NOW()', FALSE);
    $this->db->where('id',$id); //Specify the user we want to change
    $this->db->update('time_sign');

    // Now perform a read back
    $this->db->select("time-id, timein, timeout");
    $this->db->where('id',$id); // Specify the user we want to read back
    $query = $this->db->get('time_sign');
    return $query->result();
}
```

And I'd be checking your current table as it appears that you'll have 3 entries in there, as your inner loop is grabbing all 3 entries, hence the repeats.

There is more to discuss here regarding your view but thats all I have time for.

Comment: thank you for this answer I'm going to edit now I'll be back

Comment: I realize that I'm passing the ID from USERS table and I'm reading from another table time_sign. I'm trying to get this part for now... @TimBrownlaw

Comment: Well I am assuming  that your $id is related to your user id. That's how you are tying the user and time_sign tables together. Is that correct? But thinking on this a little... How are you creating the time_sign entry in the first instance. An entry in time_sign for a user has to exist before you can update it. Can you explain what you have setup in more detail.

Comment: I don't know but the  table now is empty... Is there any way to directly display data from two tables in one controller method? @TimBrownlaw

Comment: Yes, I used sql query: users.id = time_sign.indexuser so that the record will find the time in/out of that particular id. I set id from users table and indexuser from time_sign table as foreign key. But now the table (in the views) is empty. @TimBrownlaw

Comment: I edited my view file now. I removed the double loop. Now, the remaining loop is (users as user) but an error shows Undefined Property stdclass which backtraces to my view file line 72 which is the calling function of the button (<a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/tabledisplay/recTime/".$user->id; ?>">)